# envío de datos de 3 formularios a 1 base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Tengo una aplicación web app desarrollada en html y javascript.  En dicha aplicación tengo tres formularios y cada uno tiene 2 inputs diferentes. Lo que necesito es enviar la información de los tres formularios a una sola base de datos al final del formulario número 3 . La consulta es Cómo hago para

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Puedes publicar tu código? Ya que asi es más fácil ayudarte. Puedes leer: [Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), aquí te puedes asesorar sobre como formular las preguntas para que se te pueda responder más rápida y precisamente.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer algo como detectar el click de enviar los datos del último formulario, y mediante ajax hacer 3 consultas para pasar los datos, el código con jquery sería algo de este estilo (el .form1 hace referencia a un elemento del DOM con la clase form1, con #form1 accederías al elemento con el id form1):

```
$('.btnForm3').click(function(){

let form1 = $('.form1').serialize();
let form2 = $('.form2').serialize();
let form3 = $('.form3').serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "miRuta",
    data: form1, 
    success: function (res) {
        return true;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "miRuta",
    data: form2, 
    success: function (res) {
        return true;
    }
});


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "miRuta",
    data: form3, 
    success: function (res) {
        return true;
    }
});

});
```

y ya en un archivo php o en node, resuelves el formulario para hacer los insert, uno a uno, o si no guarda todos los datos en una variable y resuelvelo en una sola llamada, espero que te sirva

Comment: Gracias Yandrak!  ya reviso!  :)